# F710 lost my nano reciever, can I connect with bluetooth dongle as alternative?

Tags: pc, controllers

Hi my problem is exactly as the title says, Im planning to buy a bluetooth(4.0) dongle so I could use my [Logitech F710-Gamepad](http://gaming.logitech.com/de-de/product/f710-wireless-gamepad) again.
But to play it safe, I need to know first if it would realy work before going to the store.

And I'd like to know if there are disadvantages from using bluetooth as a reciever.
like if there are delayed button response or smaller signal radius or frequent unresponsiveness.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The F710, like most other wireless products Logitech makes do not use bluetooth but their own protocol.

You can buy a new receiver by contacting Logitech Support: http://support.logitech.com/en_us/home

Comment: Also note that the F710 does not use the same wireless protocol as many of Logitech's other products either - you cannot connect the F710 to a Unifying Receiver. It can only be used with a NANO receiver specifically built to be used with the F710.

Comment: Once a new NANO receiver is obtained, how do you link the existing F710 controller with the new receiver?

Comment: @Frac I would assume such a thing would come with instructions. I do not know I have never needed to do it.