# F710 lost my nano reciever, can I connect to Logitech unifying receiver?

Tags: pc, controllers

Hi my problem is exactly as the title says, I'm planning to buy a Logitech unifying receiver so I could use my Logitech F710-Gamepad again. But to play it safe, I need to know first if it would really work before going to the store.

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270021/f710-lost-my-nano-reciever-can-i-connect-with-bluetooth-dongle-as-alternative)

Comment: Cursory research seems to suggest that the F710 does not work with a unifying receiver, but you can contact logitech support to get a new F710 receiver.